# PowerShell Add-Member ... odd behaviour?

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject, add-member

Can anyone explain what appears to be odd behaviour when using **Add-Member** to add an attribute to a **PSCustomObject** object?  For some reason, once you've added the member, the object is represented like a **hashtable** when displayed, even though it's still a **PSCustomObject**, e.g.:

Create a simple object:

```
[PSCustomObject] $test = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; }
```

Check its type:

```
$test.GetType();
```

...which returns:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

Then get its contents:

```
$test;
```

...which returns:

```
c b a
- - -
3 2 1
```

Add a property:

```
Add-Member -InputObject $test -MemberType NoteProperty -Name d -Value 4 -TypeName Int32;
```

Confirm its type hasn't changed:

```
$test.GetType();
```

...which returns:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

Finally, get its contents again:

```
$test;
```

...which returns:

```
@{c=3; b=2; a=1; d=4}
```

Whereas I was hoping to get:

```
c d b a
- - - -
3 4 2 1
```

Any thoughts would be welcome, as I've been picking away at this for ages.

Many thanks

Comment: There is a semicolon to much in the hashtable of constructor. It should be: `@{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 3 }`

Comment: Also: [**Avoid Using Semicolons (`;`) as Line Terminators**
PowerShell will not complain about extra semicolons, but they are unnecessary, and can get in the way when code is being edited or copy-pasted. They also result in extra do-nothing edits in source control when someone finally decides to delete them.](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/blob/master/Style-Guide/Code-Layout-and-Formatting.md#avoid-using-semicolons--as-line-terminators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Omit the `-TypeName Int32` argument** in the [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) call: **it does *not* specify the `-Value` argument's type**.

```
# Do NOT use -TypeName, unless you want to assign the custom
# object stored in $test a specific ETS type identity.
Add-Member -InputObject $test -MemberType NoteProperty -Name d -Value 4
```

Note that `Int32` (`[int]`) is *implied* for an unquoted argument that can be interpreted as a decimal number that fits into the `[int]` range, such as `4`.

If you do need to specify the type explicitly, use a *cast* in an *expression*, e.g. `... -Value ([long] 4)`

---

As for **what you tried**:

**`-TypeName Int32` assigns the full name of this type, `System.Int32`, as the first entry in the list of *ETS type names*** associated with the *input object*. (ETS is PowerShell's [Extended Type System](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763).)

You can see this list by accessing the [intrinsic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) `.pstypenames` property (and you also see its *first* entry in the header of [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member)'s output):

```
PS> $test.pstypenames

System.Int32
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
System.Object
```

As you can see, `System.Int32` was inserted before the object's true .NET type identity (`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`); the remaining entries show the inheritance hierarchy.

Such **ETS type names are normally used to associated custom behaviors with objects**, irrespective of their true .NET type identities, notably with respect to ***extending* the type** (see [about_Types.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Types.ps1xml)) or **associating *custom display formatting*** with it (see [about_Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml)).

Since PowerShell then thought that your `[pscustomobject]` was of type `[int]` (`System.Int32`), it applied its usual output formatting for that type to it, which in essence means calling `.ToString()` on the instance.

Calling `.ToString()` on a `[pscustomobject]` instance results in the hashtable-*like* representation you saw, as the following example demonstrates:

- Note the use of the PSv3+ *syntactic sugar* for creating the `[pscustomobject]` instance (`[pscustomobject] @{ ... }`), which is not only more efficient than a [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) call but also *preserves the property order*.

```sh
PS> ([pscustomobject] @{ a = 'foo bar'; b = 2}).psobject.ToString()

@{a=foo bar; b=2}
```

<sup>Note the use of the intrinsic `.psobject` property, which is necessary to work around a long-standing bug where *direct* `.ToString()` calls on `[pscustomobject]` instances return the *empty string* - see [GitHub issue #6163](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163).</sup>